# How do I check to see if an item is in a list, and then prints the list(if the item is in said list)?

Tags: python, list

the lists mammals, amphibians, and reptiles contain a list of animals

```
name = input("please input a animal ")
if name in mammals or name in amphibians or name in reptiles: 
    print (idk what to put here) 
else: 
    print ("it is not there")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anthony is right that you can't print a variable's name directly, but we *can* do something like this:

```
name = input("please input a animal ")

if name in mammals:
    print("mammals")
elif name in amphibians:
    print("amphibians")
elif name in reptiles:
    print("reptiles")
else: 
    print ("it is not there")
```

First, this checks if the animal is included in the list `mammals`. If it is, we print "mammals". We do the same for amphibians and reptiles. If the animal is in neither of those, we print "it is not there".

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to iterate on each list and check if it contains the name, if yes, you can print the list:

```
name = input("please input a animal ")
for l in (mammals, amphibians, reptiles):
    if name in l:
        print(l) 
else: 
    print ("it is not there")
```

Comment: thanks for the help! but is there a way to print the list name? for example, if user input was "cat," the output would be mammals?

Comment: no, the name of the variable if not accessible as a string

Comment: unless you store each list as value in a dictionnary where the key is the animal group name, and then loop over the dictionary using .items()